# .sort() 2D array javascript comparing the second item

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So I have this array and I need to order it alphabetically by the second item `(newInv[x][1])`. I tried making a `compareFunction` but didn't work. Help! Thanks.

```
newInv = [
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to identify what you've done wrong, and explain why, when you haven't included your non-working code.

I would assume, however, that your problem was in implementing the compare function. The compare function needs to take two arguments, two items from your array being sorted, and return:

- `1` (or any positive integer) if the first item comes *after* the second item in your sort order
- `0` if they are 'the same'
- `-1` (or any negative integer) if the first item comes *before* the second item in your sort order.

Here is a compare function that does what you want:

```js
newInv = [
[2, "Hair Pin"],
[3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
[67, "Bowling Ball"],
[7, "Toothpaste"]
];

compareFn = function(a, b) {
  if (a[1] == b[1]) return 0;
  return a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : -1;
};

newInv.sort(compareFn);

alert(newInv);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort()` method in combination with `localeCompare()` to return sorted array.

```js
var newInv = [
  [2, "Hair Pin"],
  [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
  [67, "Bowling Ball"],
  [7, "Toothpaste"]
];

var result = newInv.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1].localeCompare(b[1])
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

```
newInv = [
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];

//classical nested loop for sorting

for(i=0;i<newInv.length;i++)
{
  for(j=i+1;j<newInv.length;j++)
  { 
    //alphabetical comparing of second elements

    if(newInv[i][1].localeCompare(newInv[j][1])>0)
    {
        //swapping values
        var x=newInv[i];
        newInv[i]=newInv[j];
        newInv[j]=x;
    }
  }
}

//display sorted array
console.log(newInv)
```